# curl json object as POST data from json array file using jq in a loop

Tags: bash, jq

Here is my sample test.json file

```
[
    {
        "description": "Some description",
        "name": "Some name",
        "summary": "Some summary. "
    },
    {
        "description": "Some description",
        "name": "Some name",
        "summary": "Some summary. "
    },
    {
        "description": "Some description",
        "name": "Some name",
        "summary": "Some summary. "
    }
]
```

Here is the bash script

```
declare -A values=( )
while IFS= read -r value; do
  echo "Read  $value" >&2
  #echo $value | curl -d @- -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://example.com/api/foo
done < <(jq -r '.[]' <$1)
```

This is the output that I get

```
Read {
Read    "description": "Some description",
Read    "name": "Some name",
Read    "summary": "Some summary. "
Read }
Read {
Read    "description": "Some description",
Read    "name": "Some name",
Read    "summary": "Some summary. "
Read }
Read {
Read    "description": "Some description",
Read    "name": "Some name",
Read    "summary": "Some summary. "
Read }
```

I want to use the JSON objects in the file, to POST data to an API using curl.  I would expect the loop to run three times.

How do I get entire JSON object (resulting in the loop running 3 times) instead of outputting every single line from the test.json file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `jq -c`, to emit each result on a separate line. *Don't* use `-r` when your intended output is JSON, not a raw string.

I've also added some quotes below, which were missing from your code:

```
# for readability, factored out
args=( -d @- -H "Content-Type: application/json"  )

while IFS= read -r value; do
  echo "Read  $value" >&2
  curl "${args[@]}" https://example.com/api/foo <<<"$value"
done < <(jq -c '.[]' <"$1")
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much.